# How to identify touched Cell from UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using UIPanGestureRecognizer to "drag" a Cell. The problem I face is to how identify the touched Cell? The didSelectRowAtIndexPath won't work for me because the user is actually panning from the cell and not selecting it. Does anyone have any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the gesture recognizer to the `UITableView`, then in your gesture recognizer target do this:

```
CGPoint locationOfPan = [recognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:locationOfPan];
```

you can then get the cell from the table view

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```